# How can I compare two commit diffs in magit?

Tags: magit, ediff

I want to directly compare the diffs of two commits in emacs (rather than seeing the diff of two trees at given commit points).

A bonus would be being able to use ediff mode to compare the two buffers.

However there seems to be no way to have two `*magit-revision*` buffers open at once. Even if I rename the first, `(magit-visit-ref)` still updates that buffer.

I've looked through the manuals but couldn't find a reference to what controls the new buffer creation. Any ideas?

Comment: Not clear to me if you're asking to get a diff between two commits, or look at two diffs from two commits at once.

Comment: @npostavs: the second, I want to compare the two commits side by side to see what changed in a particular changeset rather than over the whole tree.

Comment: Have you tried running `magit-toggle-buffer-lock` on the first revision buffer rather than renaming it?

Comment: @KyleMeyer: ahh that makes sense - and works ;-)

Comment: @KyleMeyer: are you going to write up your answer or do you want me to do it?

Comment: @stsquad No, I'm not.  Go for it.

Comment: @KyleMeyer I wrote up your answer -- thanks! Exactly what I was looking for too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on Kyle Meyer's comment to the OP -- thanks, Kyle.

It seems that what you want is to see the diffs associated with the two commits in two separate *magit-revision* buffers.  You can accomplish this by loading up the first diff in the usual way (e.g. by hitting `RET` on it in a log view), running `M-x magit-toggle-buffer-lock` so that the buffer becomes pinned to that particular view, and then loading up the second diff in the usual way.

Without `M-x magit-toggle-buffer-lock`, Magit would reuse the buffer containing the first diff, erasing it and putting the second diff there instead.  With `M-x magit-toggle-buffer-lock`, Magit is "forced" to create a new buffer for the second diff, which is what you want.

Note that djangoliv's answer does something different; it starts up an ediff session comparing the versions of a file from two different different commits.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it from the `magit-log` buffer

- `M-x magit-log`
- E r ref1..ref2

Comment: You can do it from the status buffer too (although seeing the log will help to find the refs, of course)

Comment: This does get what I want, almost, is it possible to show the revisions side by side for all files or do I need to compare a file at a time?

Comment: you need to compare a file at a time.

Comment: brilliant, should be the answer. I wonder if there is a way to Ediff bunch of files from one commit to another rather than Ediffing files one by one between these two commits.