# Use magit to display the difference between two branches

Tags: magit, diff

Is there a way to bring up a big list of the differences between specific commits across two branches?

I tried the method described in [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/38874/296) but it came back empty, I assume because the revisions are on different branches.

I'll happily use another method if magit isn't right.

As clarification, this is the result I get from running `d r` from `magit-status` on the range `368513582b027bfde77cb2e9e43eace1b6f5336c..53ebfb70079bb5bc411fd0f8853673c2c5eb0589` which are across two branches (master and WW-pilot) and the branches are very different.

[image: empty diff]

Comment: The linked answer is exactly the solution you want.  Just use the two commit refs in question as START and END (or you can use the branch names, if you want to compare the heads of two branches).  You'll need to describe the problem in more detail if that isn't working.  (You can do this on the command line as well with `git diff START..END` but that's no different to doing it in Magit.)

Comment: I've described as best I can. I put in the two refs and the window comes up saying empty. I'll add a screenshot in a bit.

Comment: I would assume that there are indeed no differences between the two refs that you gave it.  Unless you have the "limit to files" filter enabled?  Do you get a different response from the command line?

Comment: I would be worried if there were no differences as they are very different branches (for example, completely different login methods). I will try a different diff method on a single file from the revisions to see what's up.

Comment: Does using git diff on the command line show differences?

Comment: `Git diff` doesn't work for me as it can't find kdiff.

Comment: Do you have `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` set to `kdiff`?  Or maybe in `git config diff.external`?  Or it could be coming from .gitattributes.  Maybe try `git diff --no-ext-diff`.

Comment: You might also be interested in [git-range-diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff): “Compare two commit ranges (e.g. two versions of a branch)”.  (Requires a relatively recent version of git(1).)

Answer (score 16):

I think that the command you're looking for is `magit-diff-range`. Being on some branch, hit `M-x` and `magit-diff-range`. Then, when prompted, enter the name of the other branch and you will get a buffer with diffs.

Comment: On my system, I can get this feature with “d r”.

Answer (score 2):

> `Git diff` doesn't work for me as it can't find kdiff.

I don't know why `git diff` would need `kdiff` (whatever that is), but if `git diff` does not work on the command line, the various `magit-diff-*` commands also won't work because they get the diff by running `git diff` too.

It appears to me that you have misconfigured Git. You can probably fix that by running `git config --unset diff.external` and/or
`git config --global --unset diff.external`.

Comment: I can see the diffs between the last commit and what I'm working on, from the magit-status screen. Does that use a different diff?

Comment: Magit always uses `git diff ...` to get diffs.

Comment: Use ``d c-u r`` to use ``git diff ..`` instead.